# top-level statement error for builder in program.cs file

Tags: c#, reactjs, .net

I have a React.js project using the .NET 6.0 framework. For some reason I get an error in my program.cs file which looks like this:

```
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
var app = builder.Build();
// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();


app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html"); ;

app.Run();
```

the error I get is:

**
CS8802  Only one compilation unit can have top-level statements.
**
It is always the first line of code thats targeted.

I have version checked my project and made sure it is in .NET 6. Does anyone know what this error is referring to? This is the default layout that VS provided.

[The layout (default provided by vs)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jhFEt.png)

Comment: Well it sounds like you've got at least one *other* source file with top-level statements... that's what the error message says. Have you checked every source file?

Comment: That makes sense. I just have no clue how to find it. Should there be only one source file?

Comment: There should only be one source file *with top-level statements*. That's the entry point, basically.

Comment: Could there be another file in your directory, but not visible in your project?

Comment: It seems like WeatherForecast.cs (see image above) is defined as a source-file. I have found no other hidden files. Apologies for being a bit green, quite new to this whole ordeal :).

Comment: Open a terminal and do a `dotnet clean` before, make sure you remove `obj/` and `bin/` folder, and then do a `dotnet build`. Also double check that you have cd your terminal at the root of your project, not a folder higher.

Comment: Given your screenshot, it seems that your dependencies are not fully restored. Again, use the terminal (it makes sure that your error is not Visual Studio related), and also try a `dotnet restore` after the clean and before the build. `build` is supposed to perform the restore if needed, but given your point, I advise you to double check every step.